# String not referenced properly in C# structure with Layout

Tags: c#, structure

I have a structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SERVER_USB_DEVICE
{
    USB_HWID usbHWID;
    byte status;
    bool bExcludeDevice;
    bool bSharedManually;
    ulong ulDeviceId;
    ulong ulClientAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    string usbDeviceDescr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    string locationInfo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    string nickName;
}
```

When I pass it in a win32 DLL function as below:

```
[DllImport ("abc.dll", EntryPoint="EnumDevices", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool EnumDevices(IntPtr lpUsbDevices,
                                      ref  ulong pulBufferSize, 
                                      IntPtr lpES);
```

I get some missing text in the string members of the structure.

Suppose SERVER_USB_DEVICE.usbDeviceDescr contains value "Mass Storage Device" which is wrong  it should contain value "USB Mass Storage Device"

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: What does `USB_HWID` look like?

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong here, string can not get truncated from beginning ever, if you think you missed some text, it must be from the end, please check the device/help properly.

Comment: i checked the docs throughlly actually to be frank i coded the same thing in vc++ it works fine but not in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i was making a small mistake here ulong is 8 bytes in c# where as it is 4 bytes in c++ (as we all know). converting ulong to uint solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ByValTStr` instead of `ByValArray`

Comment: well i changed to ByValTStr  but no effect

Comment: OK... could you post the C signature for the EnumDevices function ?

Comment: BOOL EnumDevices( 
 PFT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE lpUsbDevices, 
 PULONG pulBufferSize, 
 PFT_ERROR_STATE lpES 
 );

Comment: You could try to specify an array of SERVER_USB_DEVICE rather than an IntPtr in the C# declaration

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the fields in the structure that are located before `usbDeviceDescr` (`status`, `bExcludeDevice`, `bSharedManually`, `ulDeviceId`, and `ulClientAddr`) get their correct values? Could it be that it is the marshalling of the `USB_HWID` structure that is wrong, so that the offsets are off by 4 bytes for the rest of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the structure in a byte array to make sure you have everything aligned properly.  Try this:

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SERVER_USB_DEVICE));
byte[] buffer1 = new byte[size];
SERVER_USB_DEVICE[] buffer2 = new SERVER_USB_DEVICE[1];
// put instance of SERVER_USB_DEVICE into buffer2
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, buffer1, 0, size);
```